# css make image push over text

Tags: css

I must be having an off day, I'm being confused by css.

I have an image that may or may not exist. With minimal markup I would like to push over an entire block of text so that it doesn't wrap under the image if it's too long. Normally I would just float the image and use a set margin, but since the image won't be there sometimes I want a more flexible solution. Maybe this illustration will help.

[image]

I can't think of any way to do it without extra markup or dynamically using two different classes. Most of what I've tried involves floating one or both elements. The p doesn't have a set length so putting padding-bottom under img is either not enough in some cases or causes unnecessary space if p is too short. Any suggestions?

Edit: Here's a jsfiddle courtesy of Mark Adams, but it's pretty much where I'm stuck at.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cGQ6K/4/)

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just make the image float left?  Or am I missing something from your question?

Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/cGQ6K/

edit- or did you want the image to disappear if there's an overflow on the paragraph or something like that?

edit2-after adding more text to my paragraph in my jsfiddle I think I know what you mean now...I'll try to work out a solution

edit3 - here is the solution you want : http://jsfiddle.net/cGQ6K/7/ It uses a little hack though.

Comment: You are correct, long text wraps under the image and is what I hope to avoid.

Comment: Looks like what I needed. I'll test in my real world case let you know how it goes (hopefully with a green checkmark)

Comment: Works in Chrome, FF, Opera, and IE 9, 8, and 7. Thank you sir!

Comment: You're welcome, although I'm sure there's a way to do it without the hack.

Comment: You're probably right, but as hacks go, that's not a bad one. Treats all browsers the same, doesn't look like ascii art, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you get the problem since the Mark Adams example works, but I believe that in some cases we could solve with the "clear" CSS property.

We most use "clear:both" but you can try "clear:right" or "right" for the image.

See here the reference of CSS Clear property:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

Comment: Clearing would force the text below the image. Not desired.

Comment: check my last edit and tell me if that is what you're looking for